# How to sort a List of generic objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, generics, comparator

I'm struggling with sorting an `ArrayList` of a generic objects.

I've tried to do it with `Comparable` interface, but it doesn't work, I've also tried with sort method of collections, but I'm still at the same point.

```
public class League<T extends Player> implements LeagueComparator<T> {
    private String name;

    private ArrayList<Team<T>> teams = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
    public void ranking(){
        for (Team<T> team : teams){
            System.out.println(team.getName() + team.ranking());
            int ranking = team.ranking();

            Collections.sort(teams, new Comparator<Team<T>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Team<T> o1, Team<T> o2) {
                    return
```

In this method, I want to take a ranking integer from Team class and sort it, and then return the sorted values

```
public class Team<T extends Player> {
    private int size = 0;
    private String name;
    private int games;
    private int win;
    private int lose;
    private int draw;

    private ArrayList<T> members = new ArrayList<>();

    public int ranking(){
        return (win * 2) + draw;
    }
```

This is Team class
EDIT

```
    System.out.println(team.ranking() + " " + team.getName());         
    Collections.sort(teams, Comparator.comparingInt(team::rankings));  
    System.out.println(team.ranking() + " " + team.getName());
```

Now it throws

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Comment: `League ... implements LeagueComparator<T>` This is wrong. A league might be comparable to other leagues. That doesn't mean it *can compare leagues*. Comparable != Comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Comparable

> I tried with `Comparable` interface but it doesn't work

If there's **only one way** to compare *teams* that make sense from the perspective of your application - by their *ranking*, then `Team` objects have a *natural ordering* and hence class `Team` should implement `Comparable`.

A quote from the [*documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's ***natural ordering***, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its *natural comparison method*.

That's how it might be done:

```
public static class Team<T extends Player> implements Comparable<Team<T>> {
    public static final Comparator<Team<? extends Player>> BY_TEAM_RANKING =
        Comparator.comparingInt(Team::ranking);
    
    // fields, getters, etc.

    public int ranking() {
        return (win * 2) + draw;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Team<T> other) {
        return BY_TEAM_RANKING.compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

For the sake of conciseness, method `compareTo` in the code shown above internally uses `Comparator` defined as a `static` field (*similar approach you can find in the book "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch, have a look at it for more information on implementing `Comparable` interface*).

To sort the *list of teams*, use method `sort()` directly on the list (which is a more fluent alternative of `Collection.sort()` introduced with Java 8).

```
public class League<T extends Player> {
    
    private String name;
    private List<Team<T>> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void ranking() {
        teams.sort(null); // teams are comparable, hence no need to provide a comparator and null is passed as an argument
    }
}
```

## Comparators

In case if there are **multiple ways** how teams need to be sorted in different scenarios, then `Team` class should not implement `Comparable`, don't go with way.

You can define comparators for different use-cases as `public static` fields in the `Team` class, like below:

```
public static class Team<T extends Player> {
    
    public static final Comparator<Team<? extends Player>> BY_TEAM_RANKING =
        Comparator.comparingInt(Team::ranking);
    
    public static final Comparator<Team<? extends Player>> BY_TEAM_NAME =
        Comparator.comparing(Team::getName);
    
    // the rest code
}
```

And then apply them depending on a particular case:

```
public void ranking() {
    teams.sort(Team.BY_TEAM_RANKING);
}
```

***Sidenote:*** write your code against interfaces, **not** implementations like `ArrayList`. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 1):

Simply returns the difference in ranking of o1 and o2.

```
Collections.sort(teams, new Comparator<Team<T>>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Team<T> o1, Team<T> o2) {
    return o1.ranking() - o2.randking();
  }
});
```

Comment: It's 2022 ;) `Comparator.comparingInt(Team::ranking)`

Comment: Okay, so just to make sure I understand it, first i create for each loop, so I can get every element from generic ArrayList that contains objects of Team class, then I sort objects with `Comparator.comparingInt(Team::ranking)`, I edited what I wrote

Comment: You don't need a loop.  Collections.sort will perform the sorting using the comparator to help it decide the ordering of the Team objects in the list teams.  You should use whichever you understand.